# Ruby (on Rails) associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these code snippets (I'm just learning RoR btw, so please take it easy on me, I did some googling already ;)):

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

and this

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

and this one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
  end
```

There's nothing difficult going on here. I understand everything. One thing I don't get though is this quote (concerning the tutorial by Michael Hartl that I'm reading):

> Once we define the proper associations, the resulting @micropost
>   variable will **automatically** have user_id equal to its associated user.

Now how is Rails able to do this and why is this automatically done? Any effort at explaining this will be much appreciated.

Comment: sorry but this isn't the right place to ask this kind of question.  You can ask that in the ruby on rails forum.

Comment: And the tutorial should explain this (or better yet, the Rails book actually explains in depth). The [Rails guides also cover it pretty well](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is all about "convention over configuration"  the idea is, if you play by a certain number of rules, then Rails can take care of a lot of things for you.  When you say "User has many Microposts and a Micropost belongs to the user in each model, the Rails automatically knows that the user_id field in Microposts table point to the id field in the User model, and the micropost_id field in the User table points to the associated id field in Microposts.  You can then do this:

@user.microposts to get all the micro posts for that user
@micropost.user to get the user of the microspost.

For this "magic" to work, you need to declare the "has many" and "belongs to" arguments in the models themselves, and name the keys correctly "user_id" and micropost_id otherwise it won't work.

Comment: so you're trying to say that upon making the model, if i created `usr_ids` instead of `user_id` it wouldn't work. meaning Rails looks for the words `user` and `id` right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it knows the two belong to each other.  Naming is important as well.  There is a difference between User.microposts and Micropost.users.  The plural is the "many" of the relationship, and the singular is the "one".

Comment: thanks a lot. i wouldn't have know how else Rails could "automatically" know this.